# What is the proper format for typing React props in TSDoc?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typedoc, tsdoc

I'm trying to apply the TSDoc standard for comments to a React project written in Typescript (with an eye towards generating documentation with Typedoc), but can't find any definitive answers for the preferred way to annotate a React `props` object. I've got this so far, where `MyProps` is an interface:

```js
/**
 * Description of my function component
 * @param props - React props
 */
export default function MyComponent(props: MyProps) { ...
```

Is there a preferred method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to document the props interface, and not the component itself. Which means this is the same as [documenting fields of an interface.](https://github.com/microsoft/tsdoc/issues/246#issuecomment-661581283)

```
import React from 'react'

interface FooProps {
  /** Testing 123 */
  foo: string
}

function Foo({foo}: FooProps) {
  return <>{foo}</>
}

<Foo foo="bar" />
```

When you hover over `foo=` on the last line, you should see the documentation.

[image]

[Playground example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAMQggAUcwBnOAb1LhwA9ACoRcACpIuMKgHM4ARgBMAZjgihAuJlYAuODKjzSAX3KYArpQzAIlZqwAUvXRFMGW7TlwCUfbSIYSygHAB4APldWUzChCLNyMK8dVgBeACIAIxQoDOEIoA)